# Do the capacitors on the picture look broken?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I have here a CD player's board (the player is from 80s, *Gründig CD 30*), the player works OK first 10 seconds, after that there is **loud noise** (sound is still possible to recognize but is very very cracky). The capacitors [on the picture] look somehow strange to me, particularly those **orange spots**. Could it be the symptom of broken capacitor?

**Update:**
thanks for the answers, the capacitors are really not broken, with no adjustments I assembled the player and the problem is gone, no noise at all. Mystic. So those orange spots seem to be some kind of glue. Thanks for the answers once again.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture if those are just marker marings or not, but it is possible that a 34 year old board's caps to leak or dry out. If you suspect the caps, you can ue a scope to see if they are working, or bite the bullet and replace them with some low esr caps with similar specs.

Comment: Asking if capacitors look damaged, is a valid question involving specific troubleshooting steps and understanding of the design!  Powertripping mod.  [mod Nick: This was written in all capitals.  I took a powertripping liberty to remove the all capitals.]

Comment: The yellow substance is adhesive, not capacitor electrolyte. What are the values of the capacitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those do not look broken.
Generally electrolytic capacitors will have scored lines so that if they do break, the lines will pop due to internal pressure.

The orange bit does seem funky but I would probably write it off as some of that gunc used to hold the capacitors down.

Comment: The pressure vent may very well be underneath on those caps. That brown stuff looks like leaked electrolyte.

Comment: @alexeyf damaged capacitors usually burst either [from the bottom side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Fdi.jpg) or [the top side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AFTmX.jpg), so any leak should have similar visuals.